# How to find out the number of subscribers who match criteria?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, filters, marketing-cloud-connect

I have Marketing Cloud synchronized with Sales Cloud for sending email communications, therefore I have all data in sync Data Extensions.

When creating an audience for an Email Send, I would like to find out how many subscribers match the entry criteria before activating the journey.

The only way I can think of is creating the audience from a Sales Cloud report and use campaign members. I would like to know if there is any other way to get this number from the Marketing Cloud platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options for doing this in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. In order of rising complexity:

1. Filtered Data Extension: You can run a filter on the data extensions (if the criteria is simple and one of the data extension fields i.e Gender = Female or DateCreated = Today)
2. SQL Query : If you want to use a complex filter criteria, you would need to perform queries in Automation Studio. This requires knowledge of T-SQL

**Resources:**

- [Filtered Data Extension](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_filtered_data_extension/)
- [SQL Query Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Using the Filtered Data Extension, is there any way to link tracking data from the subscriber with the contactId in order to sync it back to Sales Cloud?
We were using Salesforce Data as entry data because we need to have tracking data in the CRM.